# Migrating from asp net 2.2 to 3.1 Authorization Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, migration, authorization, razor-pages

I have an issue with authentication and authorization when I migrated my web app from asp 2.2 to 3.1.
looks OK and behaves as normal with CRUD operations and other things.

In my SignIn.cshtml.cs file I have this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await signinManager.PasswordSignInAsync
        (SignInData.UserName, SignInData.Password,
            SignInData.RememberMe, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("../StartPage");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login!");
        }
    }
    return Page();
}
```

And I get a result.Succeed and the redirect to the StartPage is called.

Here is my StartPage

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Standardbruker")]
public class StartPageModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

But for some reason I`m not redirected to the start page. I`m still on the Login page.

I know this post is missing information and I can post some more details.

I have followed this [Link to article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), as good as I could

but I must have missed out something, I know.

I`m using Razor Pages.

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Hi @webtrk,Can you share your startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your code:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

before your `app.UseAuthorization();`

Like this :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Great...thank you, that was the solution. I saw I missed it as I entered the code in the post. I tried it and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here it is.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NHA_Portal.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NHA_Portal.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;



namespace NHA_Portal
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => {
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole()
                    .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Information);
                loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            });
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
             options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ManagementContext")));

            services.AddIdentity<AppIdentityUser, AppIdentityRole>()
                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
            {
                opt.LoginPath = "/Security/SignIn";
                opt.AccessDeniedPath = "/Security/AccessDenied";
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            //services.AddDbContext<ManagementContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ManagementContext")));

            services.AddDbContext<ManagementContext>(options => {
                options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ManagementContext"));
                options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            

        }
    }
}
```